# Run a function after DOM is updated from a helper function

Tags: javascript, meteor

**Edit:**

This is precisely what I want to do:

```
  Template.FrameItems.helpers({
    frames: function() {
      var trialId = Session.get('trialId');
      return Frames.find({trialId: trialId});
      // when new frames are rendered, I want to call positionElements()
    }
  });

  Template.FrameItems.onRendered(function() {
    this.autorun(function() {
      var trialId = Session.get("trialId");
      positionElements();
      // problem: positionElements() is called before the DOM is updated from `frames` helper function
    })
  });
```

**EDIT2:**

This is my second attempt which doesn't work.

```
  var frameDep = new Tracker.Dependency;
  Template.FrameItems.helpers({
    frames: function() {
      var trialId = Session.get('trialId');
      frameDep.changed();
      return Frames.find({trialId: trialId});
      // when new frames are rendered, I want to call positionElements()
    }
  });

  Template.FrameItems.onRendered(function() {
    this.autorun(function() {
      frameDep.depend();
      positionElements();
    });
```

The same problem still remains. By the time `positionElements()` is invoked, the DOM is still not updated with the new `frames` objects. I need a way to find out when the DOM is updated. `onRendered()` is not called after the very first time the template is rendered, which is problematic in my case.

**EDIT3:**

I ended up doing this, but I feel like there should be a better solution.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var frameItemsTemplate;
  Template.TrialWorkSpace.onRendered(function() {
    this.autorun(function() {
      var trialId = Session.get("trialId");
      if (frameItemsTemplate) {
        Blaze.remove(frameItemsTemplate);
      }
      frameItemsTemplate = Blaze.render(Template.FrameItems,
        $('.frame-items-container')[0]);
    });
  });

  Template.FrameItems.helpers({
    frames: function() {
      var trialId = Session.get('trialId');
      return Frames.find({trialId: trialId});
    }
  });

  Template.FrameItems.onRendered(function() {
    positionElements();
  });
}
```

And the template file

```
<template name="TrialWorkSpace">
  <div class="trial-workspace-container">  
    <div class="row frame-items-container">
      <!-- populated programmatically instead of {{> FrameItems}} -->
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template name="FrameItems">
  {{#each frames}}
    <div id="frame-{{_id}}" class="frame-preview-item cyan lighten-5">
      <div class='frame-name'>{{name}}</div>
      <div class="ep"></div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first assumption is wrong. `onRendered` only renders when the template is inserted into the DOM, if you want reactivity, you'll wanna stick an `autorun` in the callback.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.TrialWorkSpace.onCreated({
    dep = new Tracker.Dependency();
  });
  Template.FrameItems.helpers({
    frames: function() {
      var trialId = Session.get('trialId');
      console.log("I am getting called");
      dep.changed();
      return Frames.find({trialId: trialId});
    }
  });

  Template.TrialWorkSpace.onRendered(function() {
    Tracker.autorun(function() {
      dep.depend();
      console.log("onRendered");
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: I am still having troubles because it seems when `dep.changed()` is called, the `frames` helper function hasn't run completely (i.e. DOM is not updated yet with the new frames). What I need to do is alter the DOM after the new frames are rendered. Do you have any insight on this?

Comment: The easiest solution is to change `dep.changed()` to `Meteor.defer(function() {dep.changed()})`. This tells it to run the `changed` after the return completes. In the real world, what it going in your `onRendered` probably belongs in a helper. Session vars have the dep built in, so you could just use that instead.

Comment: Matt K: I like that solution. But when I applied it, there's a millisecond delay after the `frames` are rendered and then `positionElements()` is called. `Meteor.defer()` waits until after the `frames` helper is returned.. I need something like "defer, but before the DOM is updated". Do you know if anything like that exists? Destroying and inserting the template manually seems to work well but I don't like it because the code seem a little dirty.

Comment: Yeah, this is all kinds of messed up. In the future, try not to change the question so much, going from a console.log to some script that affects the DOM is gonna warrant 2 very different answers. I'm sure there's a good use case for having JS position the elements, but in a pure MV* framework, that's a violation of the view layer & should be avoided.

Comment: In this case, the elements cannot be positioned by using css because they are dynamically rendered. I can't think of any more appropriate place to perform this job.

Comment: sorting on subscription & using flexbox doesn't work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83084/discussion-between-maximus-s-and-matt-k).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved following way:

```
Template.TrialWorkSpace.onRendered(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(){
        var trialId = Session.get("trialId");
        Tracker.afterflush(function(){
           positionElements();
        }.bind(self));
    })
});
```

when `Session.get("trialId")` is set or change than it will call `positionElements()` after dom refresh.